# Meteor helper variable removes duplicate adjacent spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, meteor, whitespace

I have problem with Meteor helper variable in template.

```
<div id="window"> {{ string }} </div>
```

CSS:

```
#window {
    height: 450px;
    overflow: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

I am reading text from file.

If I set the helper variable in JavaScript like:

```
Template.oreo.helpers({
    string: function() {
        return 'Here is sentence.   After which is spaces that is being replaced by one.   '
    }
});
```

The multiple string will be replaced by one single space..

Bet when I set the text using JQuery:

```
$('#window').text('Here   is   multiple    spaces.');
```

This problem does not occur.

How can I fix this? It is really important to save the text in helper string or I will have to rewrite all of my script.

Comment: div#window is in the oreo template? I don't understand how you're getting a blank string if that's the case

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my example.

Comment: There's so much missing from this example. Reading a file? Where? And what's that got to do with the code you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you aren't accidentally trimming the string before displaying it in browser?

Comment: lol, yes! Just outputted result between string operations in my code and found the line where these space were trimmed. Thanks for your clue!